# MFMessageComposeViewController not full screen on 4" screen

Tags: ios6, sms

I'm make an iPhone app,  in this app the user can send a SMS.
On my iPhone 4 is my screen perfect, but on my iPhone 5 i get a blank box.

iPhone only. iOS 6x

**Screenhot** (iphone5): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOqu1.png

[image]

```
#import "smsview.h"

@interface smsview ()

@end

@implementation smsview

- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MessageComposeResultCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Message cancelled");
    else if (result == MessageComposeResultSent)
        NSLog(@"Message sent");
    else
        NSLog(@"Message failed");
}

- (void)sendSMS:(NSString *)bodyOfMessage recipientList:(NSArray *)recipients
{
    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
    {
        controller.body = bodyOfMessage;
        controller.recipients = recipients;
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}


-(IBAction)Text:(id)sender
{
    {
        [self sendSMS:@"" recipientList:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"+1-234-567-8910", nil]];
    }
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps if u failed to.

1. Are you using the latest version of Xcode if not download from [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12).
2. You can use the Auto layout feature and create the design the using iPhone 5 screen resolution and it will work for the both 4" and 3.5" devices, but in this case you should have a enough knowledge of layout manager.
3. Set a 4-inch launch image for your app. This is how you get 1136 px screen height (without it, you will get 960 px with black margins on top and bottom), To adapt your app to the new taller screen, the first thing you do is to change the launch image to: Default-568h@2x.png. Its size should be 1136x640 (HxW). Yep, having the default image in the new screen size is the key to let your app take the whole of new iPhone 5's screen..
4. Hopefully everything should work if you had set auto resizing masks properly.
5. If you didn't, adjust your view layouts with proper auto resizing masks or look into Auto Layout if you only want to support iOS 6 going forward.
6. If there is something you have to do for the larger screen specifically, then it looks like you have to check height of `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` (or applicationFrame, but then you need to consider status bar height if it's present) as there seems to be no specific API for that.

for instance:

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    //iPhone 4 specific
} else {
    //iPhone 5 specific
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: try one more thing then. go to MainWindow.xib, select main window and in Attributes inspector (right tab 4th option), select size and set it to freeform. now let me knoe the response.

Comment: Only in smsview is the problem.
Other views works fine on my iPhone 5